Configures ChartLines objects in openpyxl
I'm using openpyxl to plot a graph, but I'm having trouble configuring the gridlines.
Example (simplified) Code
# Import 
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.chart import LineChart, Reference
from openpyxl.chart.axis import ChartLines, TextAxis
from openpyxl.chart.shapes import GraphicalProperties
from openpyxl.drawing.colors import ColorChoice

# Create a line chart
chart = LineChart()

# Reference data from the worksheet I'm working with
num_rows = ws_data.max_row
num_cols = ws_data.max_column
data_ref = Reference(ws_data, min_col=2, min_row=1, max_col=num_cols, max_row=num_rows)
chart.add_data(data_ref, titles_from_data=True)

# Configure the x_axis
chart.x_axis = TextAxis(tickMarkSkip=4)
chart.x_axis.majorTickMark = "cross"
chart.x_axis.delete = False

# Configure the vertical gridlines
chart.x_axis.majorGridlines = ChartLines()
chart.x_axis.majorGridlines.graphicalProperties = GraphicalProperties(noFill=False, solidFill=ColorChoice(prstClr='yellow'))

# Add the chart to the 'Charts' worksheet
ws_chart.add_chart(chart, "A1")

The result of this piece of code is that the vertical gridlines are visible every 4 tickmarks as I intend. However, the color is wrong. I also tries a few other things but it seems like I can't do anything to manipulate the graphical properties of ChartLines() objects.
